# transitionWithView using ViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using following code for my transition:

```
[UIView
     transitionWithView:appDelegate.window
     duration:0.5
     options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
     animations:^(void) {
         BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];

         [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

         appDelegate.window.rootViewController = rootRegistrationVC;

         [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
     }
     completion:nil];
```

It's showing crossDissolve animation from one viewController to another, but after this animation if i try to press button in loaded view controller i get error :

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception
```

Any ideas why this is happening?